# loop cat command for all files and subdirectory

Tags: linux

I have lot of mp3 files that are in 2 languages so

language 1 is EN/1/1.mp3 .... .. EN/2/12.mp3

language 2 is DE/1/1.mp3 .... .. DE/2/12.mp3

So files are in same subfolder and same name, I want to merge them

EN/1/1.mp3 and DE/1/1.mp3 to be 1 file and to be saved on folder ENDE/1/1.mp3

I use this command

```
cat  EN/1/1.mp3 DE/1/1.mp3 > ENDE/1/1.mp3
```

and it works but I want something to that will loop this command to all files in all subfolders.

Comment: Does the resulting mp3 file work? That's really surprising,  I believed that at most only the first half of it must work.

Comment: Look into http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through the files you can use the following, but as @ekaerovets stated, I believe your file will be invalid.

```
cd EN
for F in */*.mp3; do
  mkdir -p ../ENDE/$(dirname $F)
  cat $F ../DE/$F > ../ENDE/$F
done
```

This is assuming you files are all only one sub directory deep. If the tree is deeper then `find` would be more appropriate, ie:

```
cd EN
for F in $(find -type f -name \*.mp3); do
  mkdir -p ../ENDE/$(dirname $F)
  cat $F ../DE/$F > ../ENDE/$F
done
```